# Setting a DWORD value in the registry

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I'm trying to set a DWORD value in the registry. I made it work with a text value, but now I want to set another value with a numeric one(0). But it doesnt write it.
This is my code:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\pager", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("Save"), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)0x00, sizeof(DWORD));
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

PS: the key already exist with the value 1 so I'm trying to overide it with the value 0(I'm not creating a new one).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The biggest error is in `(const BYTE*)0x00`: you are casting 0x00 to a `BYTE *`, which means that basically you are passing a `NULL` pointer. Instead, you should create a `DWORD` variable, put the value you want to store in the registry in it and pass a pointer to it instead of that `0x00`.

Also, you must change `REG_SZ` to `REG_DWORD` if you want to store a `DWORD` value, otherwise the `DWORD` will be interpreted as a (somewhat strange) string.

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\pager", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
DWORD value=0;
RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("Save"), 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

But, most importantly, you should really check the return values of these functions: now you're just "hoping" they work, ignoring any failure and continuing with the instruction flow, which can lead to unexpected situations.

If you checked the error codes you would have noticed immediately that it is the `RegSetValueEx` function that fails, and the error code may have been something like "invalid parameter", that would have pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

For the `dwType` parameter to `RegSetValueEx`, you should be using `REG_DWORD` instead of `REG_SZ`.

You should also be passing a valid pointer to a DWORD for the `lpData` parameter.

Comment: i changed it, but still no changes, it doesnt set the value 0

Comment: As Matteo suggests, you should be checking for failure and calling `GetLastError` to determine what's wrong (if you're using Visual C++ and debugging, you can use the pseudo-register "@err" to show the current last error value).

Answer (score 2):

Change your REG_SZ parameter to REG_DWORD.  That parameter specifies the type of the value that will be written to the registry.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724884(v=vs.85).aspx for a full list of types.