# Get ERROR_NOACCESS error on write DWORD value to registry by using C code

Tags: c, registry

I'm not strong in C code and this is my problem:

I try to write `REG_DWORD` to registry (I use minGW).

However I get an error 998 `ERROR_NOACCESS` and don't know why.

All stuff seems valid.

In my case I try to write `777`

It's really strange why so basic task, like to add value to registry seems so complicated and Google doesn't contains any information

Please, help

this is my code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
//#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500   // Windows 2000
//#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400   // Windows NT 4.0
//#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0500 // Windows ME
//#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0410 // Windows 98
//#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0400 // Windows 95
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

....

const char *WriteValue()
{
HKEY hkey;
LONG result_open, result_close;
const char *defaultVal = "0";
DWORD data = 777;
DWORD dwValue, dwType, dwSize = sizeof(dwValue);
DWORD szType = REG_DWORD;

printf("Opening Key...\n");
result_open = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
              "Software\\screen-capture-recorder",
              0, KEY_WRITE, &hkey);


if(result_open != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    if(result_open  == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
        printf("Not found\n");
    } else {
        printf("Error Opening Key\n");
    }
} else {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!\n");
}



 printf("Writing Value named capture_height\n");
 LONG result_write = RegSetValueEx(hkey, "capture_height", 0, szType, (LPBYTE)data, dwSize+1);
if(result_write != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error Writing Value\n");
} else {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!\n");
}

printf("Closing Key...\n");
result_close = RegCloseKey(hkey);
if(result_close != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error Closing Key\n");
} else {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!!\n");
}


return defaultVal;
}
```

**[Compilation]**

> $ gcc -L/local/lib -I/local/include -o readRegistry readRegistry.c

**[Run]**

```
$ ./readRegistry.exe
Opening Key...
SUCCESS!!!
Writing Value named capture_height
Error Writing Value
Closing Key...
SUCCESS!!!!
```

**[Registry before]**

[image]

**[EDIT 1]**

Regards to @Mat comment:

I get error 998, from `Winerror.h`

> ERROR_NOACCESS 998L

**[EDIT 2]**

When I run:

> LONG result_write = RegSetValueEx(hkey, "capture_height", 0, szType, (LPBYTE)"0x00000006", dwSize+1);

I get no error but in registry I see `Invalid DWORD (32-bit) value`.

I tried to use:

```
int32_t i;
i = 0x00000777; 
LONG result_write = RegSetValueEx(hkey, "capture_height", 0, szType, (LPBYTE)i, dwSize+1);
```

get the same error

**[EDIT 3]**

To be sure that i have right infra i run some test:

> LONG result_write = RegSetValueEx(hkey, "capture_height1", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)"bobo", dwSizeI*2+1);

And I get in registry right value "bobo" defined as REG_SZ

Comment: From the docs: "_If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h. You can use the FormatMessage function with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag to get a generic description of the error._" - please do that so that you know what the actual error is. Or at least print out the error code.

Comment: Thank you for comment, I get ERROR_NOACCESS 998

Comment: your code looks ok -- could you try adding `KEY_READ` in your call to `RegOpenKeyEx()` so that the 4th parameter reads `KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE`?

Comment: @EdwardClements thanks, it doesn't help, I added Edit 2

Comment: one thing a bit strange with your call is `dwSize+1` -- could you try: `LONG result_write = RegSetValueEx(hkey, "capture_height", 0, szType, (LPBYTE)data, sizeof(data));`?

Comment: Yes, I did it also. There is no problem to write `REG_SZ` but `REG_DWORD`

Comment: At last i found it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding `KEY_READ` in your call to `RegOpenKeyEx()` so that the 4th parameter reads `KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE`?

[It could be that you also need to ask for the read permission when you are updating existing values]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Edward Clements and @Mat for help,

After hours of "monkey-work" at last I did it:

I need add mode: `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`

```
 result_open = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\screen-capture-recorder", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);
```

and change `LPBYTE` to `BYTE`

```
LONG result_write = RegSetValueEx(hkey, "capture_height1", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
```

so now this is working code:

```
const char *WriteValue()
{
HKEY hkey;
LONG result_open, result_close;
const char *defaultVal = "0";


result_open = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\screen-capture-recorder", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);

if(result_open != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    if(result_open  == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
        printf("Not found\n");
    } else {
        printf("Error Opening Key\n");
    }
} else {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!\n");
}



DWORD value=777;
printf("Writing Value named capture_height\n");
LONG result_write = RegSetValueEx(hkey, "capture_height1", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));

printf("response %ld\n", result_write);

if(result_write != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error Writing Value\n");
} else {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!\n");
}

printf("Closing Key...\n");
result_close = RegCloseKey(hkey);
if(result_close != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error Closing Key\n");
} else {
    printf("SUCCESS!!!!\n");
}


return defaultVal;
}
```

I used for answer [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437800/setting-a-dword-value-in-the-registry)

Comment: `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` will normally take care of your `ERROR_NOACCESS` error, but I'm still curious why a 'KEY_READ|KEY_WRITE' is not enough for a call to `RegSetValueEx()` -- Couldit be that the key was already present as a different type, maybe?

Comment: Yes, I checked, your answer works, i mean KEY_READ|KEY_WRITE. SO the main problem was `(const BYTE*)` instead `(LPBYTE)`. Please, post your answer I'll upvote